# Preventing Multiple Tabs with same Session state in Oracle APEX 5

Tags: session, oracle-apex

Iam using Oracle APEX 5 Universal theme.
If user copies a page URL along with session and pastes it in new tab ,  the session should expire.
i.e. Multiple tabs with same session should be restricted, at a time only one tab for that session should be valid.
For example: If user is in home page(page 1) , if they are copying the same URL of home page(page1) along with session id and pasting it in new tab, the session should expire.
Restriction of opening multiple tabs for same session.

Can anyone suggest some methods to restrict this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable access by URL by setting Session State Protection (Application => Shared Components => Security Attributes). Choose "Enable", then click Manage Session State Protection => Set Protection => select "Configure", click Next and set Page Access Protection property to "No URL Access".

> No URL Access - The page may not be accessed using a URL, however the
>   page may be the target of a Branch to Page branch type, which does not
>   do a URL redirect.